# Polynomials dense in $C^\infty(U, V)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, polynomials

Let $V$ be a Banach space and $U$ an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $C^\infty(U, V)$ denote the Fréchet space of $V$-valued smooth functions on $U$ with seminorms
$$ \| u\|_{\alpha,K} = \sup_{y \in K} | D^\alpha u(y)|$$
for each compact subset $K$ of $U$.

My question is: Are polynomials (or analytic functions) with values in $V$ dense in this space?

I could not find a definite answer so far...

Comment: What does this mean? How can you view polynomials as taking values in V?

Comment: For example by the tensor product. I don't think that the values here are so important. I would be interested in the result $V = \mathbb{R}$ as well.

Comment: Have a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39957/are-polynomials-dense-in-ck-left-barb-right. Since every open ball around some $u$ only involves finitely many of those seminorms, the same argument implies that polynomials are dense in $C^\infty$.