# Why are polynomials dense in $C^k(\bar{B})$?

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, vector-analysis

Let $\bar{B}\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be the closed unit ball. The question 
[Are polynomials dense in $C^k\left(\bar{B}\right)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39957/are-polynomials-dense-in-ck-left-barb-right) asks if the set of all polynomials are dense in 
$$C^k(\bar{B})=\{ f\in C^k(B)\mid D^{\alpha}f\text{ is uniformly continuous on bounded subsets of $B$ for }|\alpha|\le k\}.$$

The accepted answer tells us to use the induction. I do not really understand how to do this.

**Attempt**
Given Stone-Weierstrass ($C^0$), I try to show the density in $C^1$. Let $f\in C^1(\bar{B})$. We want to show that for any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a polynomial $P$ over $\bar{B}$ such that 
$$
\|f-P\|+\sum_{j=1}^{n}\|D^j f-D^j P\|<\varepsilon,
$$
where $\|g\|=\sup_{x\in \bar{B}}|g(x)|$ for $g\in C(\bar{B})$. For simplicity let $n=3$.

Following the accepted answer in the link above first note that we have
$$
f(x)=f(x_0)+\int_{x_0}^x \langle \nabla f(\gamma(r)),\gamma'(r)\rangle dr,
$$
for any nice path $\gamma$.

Now, from the density in $C^0(\bar{B})$ for any $\epsilon>0$ we can take $n$-variate polynomials $p_1,p_2,p_3$ such that
$$
\|f_x-p_1\|<\epsilon,\ \|f_y-p_2\|<\epsilon,\ \|f_z-p_3\|<\epsilon,
$$
where I used the notation $(f_x,f_y,f_z)$ for components of $\nabla f$.

It is tempting to define $P(x)=P_\gamma(x)=f(x_0)+\int_{x_0}^x \big(p_1(\gamma_1(r))\gamma_1'(r) + p_2(\gamma_2(r))\gamma_2'(r)+ p_3(\gamma_3(r))\gamma_3'(r)\big)dr$, as then we can let
$$
\|f-P\|+\sum_{j=1}^{3}\|D^j f- p_j\|=\text{small}.
$$
But the problem is we cannot say $\nabla P=(D^1P,D^2P,D^3P) =(p_1,p_2,p_3)$, can we?

My understanding is that we can say this IF $P$ is the potential of $(p_1,p_2,p_3)$. This is the case if $P_\gamma$ defined above is independent of $\gamma$, but I don't know how to say this. (Can we?)

Or do we use specific path or the domain being the ball? Or can we use more abstract discussions?

Comment: They are due to stone-Weierstrasse theorem

Comment: @GuyFsone Why? The Stone-Weierstrass I know is density in terms of $C^0$-norm topology.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Try convolving with polynomial mollifiers like $c_n(1-|x|^2/2)^n, n=1,2,\dots,$ where $c_1, c_2, \dots $ are appropriate normalizing constants.

Comment: Ah. Ok. The only mollifier I have used is that Gaussian style one. So I am guessing one can show $f* p_n$ is again polynomial (multidimensional ver. of:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/663834/is-the-convolution-of-a-function-fx-and-a-polynomial-px-always-a-polynom ) and the rest follows by a standard argument using the mollifiers? This way the argumetn used in the accepted answer (of the question that is) quoted in the question is not used.

Comment: @shall.i.am Yes I think that should work out. You can see this argument in Rudin's PMA in proving Weierstrass in one dimension. It will need a little tweaking for higher dimensions

Comment: So, extending $f$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ continuously if necessary, $f*p_n\to f$ as $n\to\infty$ on $\bar{B}$ (Brezis, Prop. 4.21). When extending $f$, let the extension have a compact support in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and also $C^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (need the smoothness of the boundary? This is fine since we have a ball).  Then, $\nabla(f*p_n)=(\nabla f)*p_n$ (Brezis, Prop. 4.20). But $\nabla f\in C(\mathbb{R}^n)$, so $\nabla(f*p_n)\to \nabla f$ as $n\to \infty$ uniformly on $\bar{B}$. ?